# How to make header that is aligned as column to be aligned as row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Im trying to make the header that is multiple row to be as a single row header, i already tried to add the header on read_csv function but it doesnt seem to be working, there is also extra gap on the column that i display i dont know what's causing it, this is the csv im trying to make the dataframe of https://gist.github.com/ktisha/c21e73a1bd1700294ef790c56c8aec1f
This is the display of the result that i code on Spyder, you can see the header is still displayed as different rows, i want it to shows as single row header [#1....      #2...      #3.... etc] and is there any way to remove the [# number.] from the header? if yes, how? and then you can also see that there's a single column that is afar from the others (extra gap) that i dont want it

[image]

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
with open("D:\python projects\pima-indians-diabetes.csv") as f:
    d = pd.read_csv(f , delimiter = ',',header = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    print (df[:4])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

so I loaded the real data now and did the following:

```
headers = pd.read_csv('pima-indians-diabetes.csv',nrows=9,header=None).loc[:,0].str.replace('# ','')
df = pd.read_csv('pima-indians-diabetes.csv',names=headers, delimiter=',',skiprows=9)
print(df)
```

1.) so for variable "headers" I only loaded the first 9 rows which contain the headers in the csv-file.

2.) I then only used column "0" and replaced the "# " there as you wanted.

3.) For the second load I skiped the first 9 rows to only load the data rows and handed the headers as the "names" parameter.

Please make sure to change the location the data is stored to your location before executing!

Loading the data two times is probably not best practice but the only way I could think of dealing with this now.

RESULT:

```
     1. Number of times pregnant  2. Plasma glucose concentration a 2 hours in an oral glucose tolerance test  3. Diastolic blood pressure (mm Hg)  4. Triceps skin fold thickness (mm)  ...  6. Body mass index (weight in kg/(height in m)^2)  7. Diabetes pedigree function  8. Age (years)  9. Class variable (0 or 1)
0                              6                                                148                                                             72                                   35  ...                                               33.6                          0.627              50                           1
1                              1                                                 85                                                             66                                   29  ...                                               26.6                          0.351              31                           0
2                              8                                                183                                                             64                                    0  ...                                               23.3                          0.672              32                           1
3                              1                                                 89                                                             66                                   23  ...                                               28.1                          0.167              21                           0
4                              0                                                137                                                             40                                   35  ...                                               43.1                          2.288              33                           1
5                              5                                                116                                                             74                                    0  ...                                               25.6                          0.201              30                           0
6                              3                                                 78                                                             50                                   32  ...                                               31.0                          0.248              26                           1
7                             10                                                115                                                              0                                    0  ...                                               35.3                          0.134              29                           0
8                              2                                                197                                                             70                                   45  ...                                               30.5                          0.158              53                           1
9                              8                                                125                                                             96                                    0  ...                                                0.0                          0.232              54                           1
10                             4                                                110                                                             92                                    0  ...                                               37.6                          0.191              30                           0
11                            10                                                168                                                             74                                    0  ...                                               38.0                          0.537              34                           1
12                            10                                                139                                                             80                                    0  ...                                               27.1                          1.441              57                           0
13                             1                                                189                                                             60                                   23  ...                                               30.1                          0.398              59                           1
14                             5                                                166                                                             72                                   19  ...                                               25.8                          0.587              51                           1
15                             7                                                100                                                              0                                    0  ...                                               30.0                          0.484              32                           1
16                             0                                                118                                                             84                                   47  ...                                               45.8                          0.551              31                           1
17                             7                                                107                                                             74                                    0  ...                                               29.6                          0.254              31                           1
18                             1                                                103                                                             30                                   38  ...                                               43.3                          0.183              33                           0
19                             1                                                115                                                             70                                   30  ...                                               34.6                          0.529              32                           1
20                             3                                                126                                                             88                                   41  ...                                               39.3                          0.704              27                           0
21                             8                                                 99                                                             84                                    0  ...                                               35.4                          0.388              50                           0
22                             7                                                196                                                             90                                    0  ...                                               39.8                          0.451              41                           1
23                             9                                                119                                                             80                                   35  ...                                               29.0                          0.263              29                           1
24                            11                                                143                                                             94                                   33  ...                                               36.6                          0.254              51                           1
25                            10                                                125                                                             70                                   26  ...                                               31.1                          0.205              41                           1
26                             7                                                147                                                             76                                    0  ...                                               39.4                          0.257              43                           1
27                             1                                                 97                                                             66                                   15  ...                                               23.2                          0.487              22                           0
28                            13                                                145                                                             82                                   19  ...                                               22.2                          0.245              57                           0
29                             5                                                117                                                             92                                    0  ...                                               34.1                          0.337              38                           0
..                           ...                                                ...                                                            ...                                  ...  ...                                                ...                            ...             ...                         ...
738                            2                                                 99                                                             60                                   17  ...                                               36.6                          0.453              21                           0
739                            1                                                102                                                             74                                    0  ...                                               39.5                          0.293              42                           1
740                           11                                                120                                                             80                                   37  ...                                               42.3                          0.785              48                           1
741                            3                                                102                                                             44                                   20  ...                                               30.8                          0.400              26                           0
742                            1                                                109                                                             58                                   18  ...                                               28.5                          0.219              22                           0
743                            9                                                140                                                             94                                    0  ...                                               32.7                          0.734              45                           1
744                           13                                                153                                                             88                                   37  ...                                               40.6                          1.174              39                           0
745                           12                                                100                                                             84                                   33  ...                                               30.0                          0.488              46                           0
746                            1                                                147                                                             94                                   41  ...                                               49.3                          0.358              27                           1
747                            1                                                 81                                                             74                                   41  ...                                               46.3                          1.096              32                           0
748                            3                                                187                                                             70                                   22  ...                                               36.4                          0.408              36                           1
749                            6                                                162                                                             62                                    0  ...                                               24.3                          0.178              50                           1
750                            4                                                136                                                             70                                    0  ...                                               31.2                          1.182              22                           1
751                            1                                                121                                                             78                                   39  ...                                               39.0                          0.261              28                           0
752                            3                                                108                                                             62                                   24  ...                                               26.0                          0.223              25                           0
753                            0                                                181                                                             88                                   44  ...                                               43.3                          0.222              26                           1
754                            8                                                154                                                             78                                   32  ...                                               32.4                          0.443              45                           1
755                            1                                                128                                                             88                                   39  ...                                               36.5                          1.057              37                           1
756                            7                                                137                                                             90                                   41  ...                                               32.0                          0.391              39                           0
757                            0                                                123                                                             72                                    0  ...                                               36.3                          0.258              52                           1
758                            1                                                106                                                             76                                    0  ...                                               37.5                          0.197              26                           0
759                            6                                                190                                                             92                                    0  ...                                               35.5                          0.278              66                           1
760                            2                                                 88                                                             58                                   26  ...                                               28.4                          0.766              22                           0
761                            9                                                170                                                             74                                   31  ...                                               44.0                          0.403              43                           1
762                            9                                                 89                                                             62                                    0  ...                                               22.5                          0.142              33                           0
763                           10                                                101                                                             76                                   48  ...                                               32.9                          0.171              63                           0
764                            2                                                122                                                             70                                   27  ...                                               36.8                          0.340              27                           0
765                            5                                                121                                                             72                                   23  ...                                               26.2                          0.245              30                           0
766                            1                                                126                                                             60                                    0  ...                                               30.1                          0.349              47                           1
767                            1                                                 93                                                             70                                   31  ...                                               30.4                          0.315              23                           0
```

---

**FIRST ANSWER:**

sample data:

```
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7        8
0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    first
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  second
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    thrid
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN        4
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN        5
5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN        6
6   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN        7
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN        8
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN        9
9     d    d    d    d    d    d    d    d        d
10    d    d    d    d    d    d    d    d        d
11    d    d    d    d    d    d    d    d        d
12    d    d    d    d    d    d    d    d        d
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
headers = pd.read_csv('test.csv',header=None).loc[0:8,8].tolist()
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',names=headers, skiprows=9)
print(df)
```

result:

```
  first second  thrid  4  5  6  7  8  9
0     d       d     d  d  d  d  d  d  d
1     d       d     d  d  d  d  d  d  d
2     d       d     d  d  d  d  d  d  d
3     d       d     d  d  d  d  d  d  d
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly how i want it, why loading the data two times is probably not best practice? and what caused the extra gap on the last column? and sorry for this very basic question, im so new at this, why i need to make sure to change the location the data is stored to my location before executing? because i think the way it displayed is okay except the extra gap,

Comment: @MumblingPotato 1.) I just meant that maybe there is a way to load the data only once and achieve the same. When datasets get really big loading the data twice can take some time. 2.) I think it just looks like a gap in your picture as row 1-9 (your headers) are broader then the rest. 3.) This was just the hint that you include your filelocation "D:\python projects\pima-indians-diabetes.csv" (instead of  'pima-indians-diabetes.csv' only) again before executing again. In my case the file and the code are in the same location so I was able to use it the way I did.